# how to pass parameter to procedure and call in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have to pass a parameter of type date to a subroutine  and use it in where clause.Is this correct way?
I am using in `date='d_date';`

Comment: Can you specify the RDBMS in the tags?

Comment: Why on earth are you using a cursor to insert row by row with no transformations? Couldn't you just insert using the select statement you are using for the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `glb_date = @d_date`

First you'll need to alter how the parameter is defined in the `CREATE PROCEDURE` definition, for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prac
(
   @d_date in DATE
)
```

Notice the `@`

Then change your `WHERE` clause to use the variable:

```
 where glb_date= @d_date;
```

Comment: This is SQL Server syntax. Just remove the `@` sign and it should run in Oracle.